# jQuery - find number of child items matching a class

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div id="DivRes">
    <div id="divGroupOne">
        <table class="tabFirstTable"> . . . </table>
        <table class="tabResult"> . . . </table>
        <table class="tabResult"> . . . </table>
    </div>
    <div id="divGroupTwo">
        <table class="tabFirstTable"> . . . </table>
        <table class="tabResult"> . . . </table>
        <table class="tabResult"> . . . </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

- All The Tables (except the first one) in each group are the same width.
- There are a different number of tables in each Group.

I need a way of finding out:

- a) what is the width of the tables in each Group with a class of `tabResult`
- b) how many tables are in each group with a class of `tabResult`.

So far I have managed to use:

```
GroupOneWidth = $('#divGroupOne').find('.tabResult').width();
```

But How can I find the number of tables in the group? Looking on Google I keep seeing results that use `.length()`

so I tried:

```
GroupOneCount = $('#divGroupOne').find('.tabResult').length();
```

but get `$(...).find(...).length is not a function`

I also tried:

```
GroupOneLength = $('#divGroupOne > .tabResult').length();
```

but get `$(...).length is not a function`

How can I get the number of items in the group?

Comment: `.length` not `.length()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length is not a function, it is a property,

```
 $('#divGroupOne').find('.tabResult').length
```

Comment: Or `$('#ID .class').length` for short.

Comment: that explains it. . . time to get my eyes tested I think. Cheers,